# C++ sort not working with compare function

Tags: c++

I am trying to sort structures stored on a vector using the sort C++ function. I have done this before without any problems. However I'm not obtaining the desired output.

If I try the compare function by itself it works, but once I use the sort C++ function the compare function doesn't seem to be working.

The idea is to sort int arrays as if they were binary numbers in ascending order. I know there are different ways of doing this, but I don't understand why this doesn't work.

The expected output is:

```
0000000000
0101010101
0110110110
```

The output is:

```
0000000000
0110110110
0101010101
```

I don't understand what happen here. Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;
int n;
struct solucion{
  int array[150];
};

vector <solucion> soluciones;

bool compare(solucion solucion1, solucion solucion2){
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    if(solucion2.array[i]>solucion1.array[i])
      return true;
  return false;
}

void print() {
  for(int i=0;i<soluciones.size();i++){
    for(int k=1;k<=n;k++)
      cout << soluciones.at(i).array[k];
    cout << endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    solucion solucion1;
    solucion1.array[1]=0;
    solucion1.array[2]=0;
    solucion1.array[3]=0;
    solucion1.array[4]=0;
    solucion1.array[5]=0;
    solucion1.array[6]=0;
    solucion1.array[7]=0;
    solucion1.array[8]=0;
    solucion1.array[9]=0;
    solucion1.array[10]=0;

    solucion solucion2;
    solucion2.array[1]=0;
    solucion2.array[2]=1;
    solucion2.array[3]=0;
    solucion2.array[4]=1;
    solucion2.array[5]=0;
    solucion2.array[6]=1;
    solucion2.array[7]=0;
    solucion2.array[8]=1;
    solucion2.array[9]=0;
    solucion2.array[10]=1;

    solucion solucion3;
    solucion3.array[1]=0;
    solucion3.array[2]=1;
    solucion3.array[3]=1;
    solucion3.array[4]=0;
    solucion3.array[5]=1;
    solucion3.array[6]=1;
    solucion3.array[7]=0;
    solucion3.array[8]=1;
    solucion3.array[9]=1;
    solucion3.array[10]=0;

    soluciones.push_back(solucion1);
    soluciones.push_back(solucion2);
    soluciones.push_back(solucion3);

    n=10;
    sort(soluciones.begin(),soluciones.end(),compare);
    print();
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Arrays start at index `0` in **C** based languages.

Comment: @K-ballo But he's ignoring index 0 in both his compare and print functions, so that's irrelevant.

Comment: Yes..but the compare function, the print function and everything begin at index 1, so there is really no problem with that

Answer (score 4):

Your comparison function does not properly establish a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) over the arrays (for example, if `solucion1 = {1,0,1}` and `solucion2 = {0,1,0}` then according to your compare function, both `solucion1 < solucion2` and `solucion2 < solucion1` will be true, which is clearly absurd).

You should change the definition comparison to something which does provide such an ordering, such as [std::lexicographical_compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare).

```
bool compare(solucion solucion1, solucion solucion2){
    return std::lexicographical_compare(
        solucion1.array+1, solucion1.array+1+n,
        solucion2.array+1, solucion2.array+1+n);
}
```

Comment: Using my comparison function solucion2>solucion1 since the element with index 1 is checked first and 1>0

Comment: @fragal: Yes, but if the comparison is done in the other order, index 1 is checked first, nothing happens, and then index 2 is checked and the comparison also returns true.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return false as soon as you see that right struct is less:

```
bool compare(solucion solucion1, solucion solucion2){
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
    if(solucion2.array[i] > solucion1.array[i])
      return true; 
    else if (solucion2.array[i] < solucion1.array[i])
      return false; 
  }
  return false;  
}
```

And a better way to initialize:

```
solucion solucion1 = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
solucion solucion2 = {{0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1}};
solucion solucion3 = {{0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0}};
```

Comment: Your compare function fixes the problem (and i noticed that i was missing to return false as soon as the right struct is less)....but I don't get why my original compare function didn't worked for this SPECIFIC case. If i use my compare function to test individually solucion2 and solucion3  it returns that solucion3>solucion2, however when passed as a parameter to the sort function it doesn't seem to be doing the same

Comment: because when system calls the function solution3 and soultion2 can change positions, meaning they can be at the right or left side. Your function cannot generate correct result when smaller one is on the right.

Comment: for example for 101 and 110 you return true, however it should be false

Comment: @fragal: The simple answer is that `std::sort` requires a comparitor that establishes a strict weak order, and so your code has undefined behaviour. The implementation of `std::sort` does not necessarily pass `solucion3` as the first argument to the comparitor and `solucion2` as the second every time.

Comment: OK, I wasn't seeing that solution3 and solution2 could change positions. Thank you so much!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

your solutions crashes for me , try

```
 bool compare(solucion solucion1, solucion solucion2){
       for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
       {
          if(solucion2.array[i]>solucion1.array[i])
               return true; 
          else
            return false;  
       }

   }
```

Comment: Testing individually 0101010101 and
0110110110   0101010101 < 0110110110 since the second number from left to right is greater for the second array (while the first number was equal). So although my compare function was not right at all, it should have worked for this case

Comment: For instance:     if(compare(solucion2,solucion3))
 cout<<"AT LEAST MY COMPARE FUNCTION SHOULD WORK FOR THIS CASE"<<endl; prints the given output